# Current Time Within javascript multi dimension array

Tags: javascript

I have got a timeslot array which has all timeslots (30 min sections) from the start to the end of the day.

```
var timeslots = new Array();
timeslots['0'] = new Array( current.setHours(0,0,0,0), current.setHours(0,29,59,0));
timeslots['1'] = new Array( current.setHours(0,30,0,0), current.setHours(0,59,59,0));
....
```

What i want to be able to do is from a specific time (use the current date/time for now) for it to search the array and get me which timeslot the current time sits within.  So if its 00:22:00 then it would be timeslot "0"

I need to have this checked regularly (preferably every second) so that i can have a ticker counting down till the NEXT timeslot...so if the current time is the same as above it will let me know that its currently in timeslot 0 and the next timeslot starts in 8 minutes....counting down...

https://jsfiddle.net/mhs8bvcj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the `timeslots` using a `for` loop and test whether the current timestamp is within the range:

```
function findTimeslot(time) {
  for (var i = 0; i < timeslots.length; i++) {
    if (timeslots[i][0] <= time && time <= timeslots[i][1]) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

To get the index of the current timeslot call the above function with the current timestamp:

```
findTimeslot(new Date().getTime());
```

To calculate the remaining time subtract the current timestamp from the end time of the current time slot.

```
var remainingMilliseconds = currentTimeslot[1] - new Date().getTime();
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9g8o632f/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can get an index with this simple math:

```
var now = new Date();
var idx = (now.getHours() * 2) + parseInt(now.getMinutes() / 30);
```

I've updated the fiddle, check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/mhs8bvcj/3/

Comment: How would I do this as a "search" of the array (incase the duration between the timeslots varys)